# How to snap to a certain section of the webpage using a react redux template

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, anchor, styled-components

I am currently using React's redux template and was trying to figure out this one last part of the code. I want to be able to have the page snap to a certain section when you click on an anchored item in the nav bar.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import styled from "styled-components";

const cars = useSelector(selectCars);

<Menu>
  {cars &&
    cars.map((car, index) => (
      <a key={index} href="...">
        {car}
      </a>
    ))}
</Menu>;

const Menu = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;

  a {
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0 10px;
    flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  }

  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    display: none;
  }
`;
```

Here a few select part of the code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**STEP 1**

Append `#` to the nav's link followed by (preferably) car's **ID**

```
<a key={index} href={`#${index}`}>
```

For the sake of simplicity and the demo I have created for you (check link below), we can use `index` from map function.

**STEP 2**

Attach `id={index}` (again, I suggest you go with `id={car.id}`) to the HTML element that represents main container of a single car (car section).

**DEMONSTRATION**

I have created a small example on [How to navigate and snap to certain section of a web page in React](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-snap-nav-link-to-section-stackoverflow-question-idk0w?file=/src/App.js)

*P.S. Have in mind that you'll need to handle snap offset in order to properly show curently selected car from the menu. I was using one trick you can find in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58224656/10415577).*